# Get the price of a currency at specific time in the past using binance historical data api

Tags: binance

I want to query the binance api for historical data but i want to indicate the specific time i want. For instance i want to know the price of etherum at 1103 hours Friday 31 August 2018.

Is this kind of thing possible on binance api?.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the klines api will suit your needs: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data

**Kline/Candlestick data**

```
GET /api/v1/klines

Kline/candlestick bars for a symbol. Klines are uniquely identified by their open time.

Weight: 1

Parameters:
Name    Type    Mandatory   Description
symbol  STRING  YES     
interval    ENUM    YES     
startTime   LONG    NO  
endTime     LONG    NO  
limit   INT     NO  Default 500; max 1000.

    If startTime and endTime are not sent, the most recent klines are returned.

Response:

[
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
  ]
]
```

Comment: how do I calculate the quote volume from the base volume, dividing them gives what? close? open? median of ohlc, average?